# Reversing a string in C using a for loop?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, reverse, c-strings

Ive been trying to reverse a string as simply as possible , trying to prove a point to myself but for some reason the code is not working. I know i can easily find a different approach online but then i wont learn anything. So would anyone explain please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   int i,n,c=0;
    char s[50];
    char a[50];
    for(i = 0; i < 50;i++)
        scanf("%[^\n]c",&s[i]);
    for(n = strlen(s), i = 0; n > i; n--,c++)
        s[c] = s[n-1];

    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and define "_Is not working_". Read this: [ask]

Comment: Why are you scanning the input in character-by-character? AFAICT your `s` buffer is not NUL-terminated when you do it like this, which will cause `strlen()` to exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: Hint: take a piece of paper, cut it in 4, write letters A to D on each of the pieces of 4 pieces of paper. Put them on a table from so they form the word "ABCD". Now apply your algorithm and you'll find out what's wrong.

Comment: It reverses up to half way , then it prints out regular text... Im trying to understand why it does that?

Comment: Okay i get it ... but damn that is really confusing

Answer (score 1):

For starters you need to include the header `<string.h>`.

This loop

```
for(i = 0; i < 50;i++)
    scanf("%[^\n]c",&s[i]);
```

does not make a great sense. Moreover you need to append the entered string with the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

What you need is to enter a string one time as for example

```
scanf("%49s", s );
```

Or even better to write

```
scanf( "%49[^\n]", s );
```

to enter a string with several words in the array.

This for loop

```
for(n = strlen(s), i = 0; n > i; n--,c++)
    s[c] = s[n-1];
```

also does not make a sense. It does not reverse the string. The variable i is not increased. That is you need to swap two characters.

Also you need to declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.

The loop can look for example the following way

```
for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n / 2; i++ )
{
    char c = s[i];
    s[i] = s[n-1-i];
    s[n-1-i] = c;
}
```

Apart from all these the declared array `a` is not used in the program.

So the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[50] = "";
 
    scanf( "%49[^\n]", s );

    for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-1-i];
        s[n-1-i] = c;
    }

    puts( s );
}
```

If to enter string

```
Hello, unikatura!
```

then the program output will be

```
!arutakinu ,olleH
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use functions.

Two variants:

```
char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char *end = str, *start = str;

    if(str && *str)
    {
        for(;*(end + 1);end++);
        for(;end > start;)
        {
            char tmp = *end;
            *end-- = *start;
            *start++ = tmp;
        }
    }
    return str;
}


char *reverse1(char *dest, const char *str)
{
    char *wrk = dest;
    size_t len = 0;

    if(str)
    {
        for(;*str;len++, str++);str -= !!*str;
        for(;len--; *wrk++ = *str--);
    }
    *wrk = 0;
    return dest;
}
```